# Error 401 in health check AWS Targer group

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elb

i'm trying to REDIRECT http automaticly to https in my EC2 instance. For that, i'm using an Application load balancer(ALB), but for associate the ALB with the instance, i added the instance in the ALB target group, i put the port (8082) and the path of the instance, but when doing the health check, it returns the following error:
"Health checks failed with these codes: [401]"

What are the possible problems that might be happening to this? And what can i do to solve it.
Also, if there's any other better solution to redirect http to https in an instance, please let me know

I already tried to search for the error, which means UNAUTHORIZED, even tho in my security group the port is already added and you can connect with the url

Comment: I imagine the healthcheck is hitting an endpoint which requires authentication. What kind of application is it? There should be a path which doesn't require you to be authenticated

Comment: @Paolo What do you mean what kind of application? You mean the instance/LB type?

Comment: What's the application running on the EC2 instance that you are routing traffic to?

Comment: It's just a REST server that i made on delphi that i can open in my domain with the port 8082, that's the only thing on the instance

Answer (score 0):

You have to make sure that in your EC2 --> "Target groups" under the "Health checks" tab the path and the port are correctly specified. Using alb ingress annotations you need these two lines:

```
alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/healthcheck-path: /path
alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/healthcheck-port: 'port'
```

Documentation is [here](https://kubernetes-sigs.github.io/aws-load-balancer-controller/v2.1/guide/ingress/annotations/)

You are getting 401 errors because of a security measure not to make information available which paths exist and which do not. So instead of 404 aws gives you 401s back.